# Can't save different colors var while changing <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

What basically i need to do is add new color, save it in a dropdown list and than when the different option are selected, i need to show the name of the color with the matched color name.
Everything works but i can't update the color name when i select a new option from my dropdown list.

Here my Html code:

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="name">Color name
    <input type="text" id="name" value="">
  </label>

  <label for="red">Red
    <input type="range" class="red" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="red" >
  </label>

  <label for="green">Green
    <input type="range" class="green" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="green">
  </label>

  <label for="blue">Blue
    <input type="range" class="blue" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="blue">
  </label>

  <label for="alpha">Alpha
    <input type="range" class="alpha" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" id="alpha">
  </label>

  <p>Rgba(0,0,0,0)</p> <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
</form>

<select id="listColors">
  <option value="">Choose your color</option>
</select>

<span></span>
```

And here the javascript:

```
window.colorApp = {}; 

    colorApp.hex = function(event){
colorApp.newRgbColor = "Rgba("+colorApp.red.val()+", "+colorApp.green.val()+", "+colorApp.blue.val()+", "+colorApp.alpha.val()+")"; 
//document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorApp.newRgbColor;
$("p").html(colorApp.newRgbColor);
     };

            colorApp.addItem = function(event){
    $(colorApp.list).append('<option>' + colorApp.name.val() + colorApp.newRgbColor + '</option>');
    $(form).trigger("reset");
    $(name).focus();
    $("p").html('Rgba(0,0,0,0)');

  };


    colorApp.displaySelectedColor = function(event){
colorApp.listSelected = $("#listColors option:selected");
colorApp.selectedColorName = $(colorApp.listSelected).text();
$('span').html('<span style="color:'+ colorApp.newRgbColor + '">'+          colorApp.selectedColorName + '</span>');
    };


  $(document).ready(function() {
colorApp.form = $('#form');
colorApp.name = $('#name');
colorApp.red = $('#red');
colorApp.green = $('#green');
colorApp.blue = $('#blue');
colorApp.alpha = $('#alpha');
colorApp.list = $('#listColors');
colorApp.input = $('input');
colorApp.input.change(colorApp.hex);
colorApp.save = $('#save');
colorApp.save.click(colorApp.addItem);
colorApp.list.change(colorApp.displaySelectedColor);

   });
```

Here the link for the live: http://designbygio.it/colorPicker2/
Any help is really welcome!!

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/qmRyR/

Comment: @Neurofluxation - nailed it.

Comment: That's how it work right now. But if you select again the old color, should display that color name with the right color text. Right now when you display the old color, still keep the text color of the new one.

Comment: Sorry, for update the color name i mean the text color of the color name. Not the color name inside of the input text

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta - sorry, what?

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to explain better, ok here an example. I add red and than blue. When i click red from dropdown i see a sentence in red color, when i click blue i see a sentence in blue color. BUT when i click again red i see a sentence in blue color. Instead i need to see this sentence in red color again

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/qmRyR/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your colorApp.addItem function you need to assign the value to the new option added,

```
colorApp.addItem = function(event){
    $(colorApp.list).append('<option value="'+colorApp.newRgbColor+'">' + colorApp.name.val() + colorApp.newRgbColor + '</option>');
    $(form).trigger("reset");
    $(name).focus();
    $("p").html('Rgba(0,0,0,0)');

  };
```

In your colorApp.displaySelectedColor function you need to add the assignment of the option value to your newRgbColor variable

```
colorApp.displaySelectedColor = function(event){
  colorApp.listSelected = $("#listColors option:selected");
  colorApp.selectedColorName = $(colorApp.listSelected).text();
  colorApp.newRgbColor=$(colorApp.listSelected).val();//you need to assign the value
  $('span').html('<span style="color:'+ colorApp.newRgbColor + '">'+             colorApp.selectedColorName + '</span>');
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBJpn/1/

Comment: I already tried this solution and unfortunately doesn't work since the val() is the whole name, not just the rgba color, so the css color property doesn't work :(

Comment: It is required to add the value property to your options with the rgba value inside colorApp.addItem . Please take a closer look at the code i posted and the jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh sorry! Now i see. Is perfect! thank you so much!!